# Как сделать такой скос у рамки?

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята подскажи плз, каким образом мне наследовать фон у body и сделать такой скок у рамки ?

Comment: Вариантом множества, идеальным (наверное), будет использование SVG

Comment: `border-image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}
.border {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  margin:10px;
  padding:15px;
  background: #58a;
  background:linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 15px, #58a 0);
}
.content {
  width: 90%; 
  height: 90%; 
  padding:10px;
  background: #fff;
  background:linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="border"><div class="content"><p>Какой то контент</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Оригинально, но не адаптивно